# Custom health check in impala

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, impala, health-monitoring

I have a use case that if a particular service is down on a node, no job should get scheduled there anymore. For Hive or Spark, I can use the concept of external health script present in Hadoop, which periodically runs the script and if service is down that script will mark node unhealthy and job won't get scheduled there anymore. But this targets YARN. Impala doesn't use YARN. I tried searching for the alternative for Impala, but couldn't find anything like a custom script. What could be the possible ways to tackle this scenario? Does Impala have a custom health check script?

Reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManager.html